# How can I reword this?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I found this in the Congressional Record. How can I reword it simpler, while keeping the same meaning?:

> Indicative of the public’s difficulty in obtaining an answer to this
>   and other questions, the Senator cited a personal experience...

Comment: Maybe [writers.se]

Comment: I could likely simplify the sentence a fair bit—but it would be based on my subjective interpretation, and no more valid an "answer" than any other.

Comment: As you see from Comments such as Phueal's Answer, that's extremely difficult, if not impossible.

What makes you think that passage can be simplified, please? If it can why d'you think it needs to be?

Even if both, how is that not purely about choice and style?

Answer (score -1):

"Highlighting the difficulty the public have obtaining an answer to this and other questions, the Senator cited a personal experience..."

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I want to simplify it because it's an exact quote and I want to paraphrase it.

Comment: Aha, ok, I thought you simply wanted an easier phrasing. Cutting it down further will lose at least some of the meaning. How about "They were very remote from the public, as shown by the Senators own story..."?